# retrieve key names from firebase react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little problem regarding Firebase and retrieving names of parent keys. Like in this example I want to get the names of the keys, not their values:

[image: quick sample of what I want to archieve]

Pls have a look in my db how it looks now, its exactly the same like in the JS sandbox:

[image]

When I try to implement this in my react-native project, basicly with plain JS in this part, it looks like this:

```
const sendletter = () => {
        console.log("letter send");
        firebase.database().
        refFromURL("https://SOMEDATABASE.firebaseio.com/numers").
        once("value").then(snapshot => {
            for(key in snapshot){
                console.log(key)
            }
        })
    };
```

The problem I just face now it the outcome of the console in my IDE:

> null letter send node_ ref_ index_ val exportVal toJSON exists child
> hasChild getPriority forEach hasChildren key numChildren getRef ref

I tried to provide you as many pictures so the problem gets really clear and also my goal I want to archieve, to get the key names itself, NOT the values the keys are linked to. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `snapshot.val()` instead of just the `DataSnapshot` object

```
for(key in snapshot.val()){
                console.log(key);
            }
```

When you are looping through just the `snapshot` variable, you are looking at all the keys in that `DataSnapshot` that is returned from firebase and not your actual data. If you check out Firebase docs, you'll see what the `DataSnapshot` object represents and how to actually get your data from the database FROM their `DataSnapshot` object that is returned: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

If you look close enough you can see that all the methods and values that this `DataSnapshot` object contains is actually what was being printed in your console all along

Comment: This worked, thank you! Can you maybe explain shortly why snapshot.val() in this case is the correct answer?

Comment: There you go, i added an explanation